# I need help passing an array and calling basic methods on it

Tags: java, arrays, class

I'm new to programming and java, and I'm trying to write a simple bubble sorting algorithm. I might be in a bit over my head; I'm not too far along in Oracle's java tutorials.  The trouble I'm having now isn't with the bubble sorting itself, but in creating the array and printing it before it is sorted.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class BubbleSort {

    public BubbleSort(int size) {

        // creates array
        int[] items = new int[size];
    }

    public void fillArray(int[] a) {

        // fill array with random ints
        for (int i=0; i<(a.length-1); i++) {
            a[i] = java.util.Random.nextInt(50);
        }
    }

    public void printArray(int[] a) {

        for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
        }
    }

    public void BubbleSortAlgorithm() {

        // bubble sorting algorithm goes here

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BubbleSort bubbleSort = new BubbleSort(20);
        bubbleSort.fillArray(items);
        bubbleSort.printArray(items);
        // bubbleSort.BubbleSortAlgorithm(items);
        // bubbleSort.printArray(items);
    }
}
```

I'm getting 3 compiler errors:

1. non-static method nextInt(int) cannot be referenced from a static context

Is this because it is called in the main method? How do I get around that?

2.,3. the compiler can't find the symbol, items. Items is an array of ints that is created in the constructor for the class. Do I need to declare it in the main method?

I have a feeling that my class structure is completely off. Again, I'm very new. I'm also new to stackoverflow, so I'm also sorry if this question isn't presented well.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We have particular rules and guidelines for asking questions, the [help/how-to-ask] is a good place to start. One problem I'm seeing is that your question doesn't appear to show research effort. It does have the relevant code (which already puts you ahead of some new users) but you haven't said what you've tried so far to fix your errors. The other is that most users consider things like "I'm new to programming and java" to be noise; they distract from the question. That can be fixed with an [edit].

Comment: Would it be possible for you to paste the actual stack trace that has the 3 errors detailed, along with where exactly they happen?  Without that, it's hard to do more than guess.  I can tell you though that the reason it can't find the symbol items is because you declare it in one of your methods, but where you try to use it in your main method, you aren't declaring.  That piece of your program has no idea what items could be.  If each of your methods are going to accept an array as a parameter anyways, you should create your array in the main method, not in the constructor of your class.

Answer (score 3):

You call:

```
java.util.Random.nextInt(50);
```

It's preferred to import classes you're going to use.  That would put this block at the top of the file:

```
import java.util.Random;
```

And change the existing code to:

```
Random.nextInt(50);
```

That fixes the style problem, but you're still going to get the same compiler error.

Static methods are things that belong to a class; they don't need you to create (instantiate) an object of that class before using them.  Instead of every instantiation of a class having that method, all instantiated instances of the class share the same static methods and variables.

Specifically, .nextInt() in the Random class is *not* a static; it's a normal method.  So it needs an instantiated Random to work on.  Which means you should try:

```
Random random = new Random();
random.nextInt(50);
```

After you've instantiated a Random, you can then keep calling nextInt() on it, as many times as you'd like.

One example of static methods that are commonly used are in the Math class.

```
Math.min(10, 5);
Math.max(100, 100000);
```

And so on.

The reason Random needs to be instantiated is that it has state.  It's not fully random, but pseudo-random, in that it needs a number to start with.  If you don't give it a number, it takes the current time.  Two Java Random objects initialized at exactly the same moment... will produce the same series of "random" numbers.

This is actually useful; you can give them Random object the number to start with, and you can use this behavior for testing purposes.

```
Random random = new Random(1);
```

That's seeding it with the number 1.  Which means it'll produce the same random numbers for nextInt() every time you run your code.  If you don't give it any number as a seed, it's doing this, instead:

```
Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

But yeah; the problem is that Random.nextInt isn't a static method.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is 
NextInt method of non static 
So you have to use instance of random class to use it
Second one 
Item is local variable so you have to must declare it before use it